# In ground spa jets not functioning properly

Tags: pool

I have an issue with my in-ground spa.

There is water coming out from the all of the jets but only 2 have very strong bubble jets coming out.

Do you think I have the an issue with clogged jets?

Answer (score 0):

If only some of the jets are not working and others are fine, then that mostly* eliminates the possibility of a clogged air inlet or bad pump or blower. So it leaves only the jets themselves, or the pipes leading to them. If the water is coming out strong from the jets, then it's likely the air pipes feeding them that are clogged, and in an in-ground spa, that's bad news because those pipes are buried in the pool deck (one of the things I don't like about in-ground spas).

If it's not just the bubbles, but the water from those jets is weaker too, then it's likely the jets themselves. SOME jets can be unscrewed and cleaned, some cannot. If yours cannot, then it might be mineral deposits in the jets clogging them and you might be able to get a stiff wire or rod (like a welding rod) in there to poke the deposits out of the openings (carefully, because you don't want to break any plastic parts). All of this is best done with the water drained to below the jet level at least.

- *In some designs, if the air inlet is partially clogged, the air pressure is insufficient to get to all of the jets, so only those CLOSEST to the inlet pull enough air through to function. In that case, you would see that the jets that are working are only those closest to the inlet.*